# Reading sql file with jinja templates in custom operator in Airflow

Tags: sql, jinja2, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to read sql file that contains query with jinja templates in the custom operator in Airflow. I have already achieved it using PythonOperator that calls function where I used

```
def execute_query(**kwargs)
    sql_query = open('my_sql_query.sql').read()   #(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > {})
    sql_query.format(kwargs['ds'])
```

but I would prefer use this syntax **{{ ds }}** directly in the query like 
`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > {{ ds }}`

What I have done:

1. I created CustomOperator with template_fields and template_ext

```
class SQLOperator(BaseOperator):

   template_fields = ['sql']
   template_ext = ('.sql',)

   @apply_defaults
   def __init__(
       self,
       name = None,
       sql = None,
       *args, **kwargs) -> None:
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.name = name
       self.sql = sql

    def execute(self, context):
       print("Name", name) # <- works
       print("Query", sql) # <- doesn't work and I don't know how to get the sql file content
```

2. Dag

```
default_args = {...}

dag = DAG(
    'sql_operator_test',
     schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
     template_searchpath=['/Users/username/airflow/dags/sql/test/'],
     default_args=default_args)

sql_task = SQLOperator(
    task_id='sql_process',
    name="Aaa",
    sql="/Users/username/airflow/dags/sql/test.sql",
    dag=dag)
```

3. SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > {{ ds }}
```

I am running out of ideas. Is there any option to pass the file to the operator or get its rendered content?

Comment: What DB are you connecting with? sql is already templated field of built-in sql operator, so you are supposed to be able to write your desired templated sql in file and use DB operator.

 ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.html

Comment: I use Postgres. Thank you @Emma. I will try to inherit from PostgresOperator. But what if I would like to pass two different queries?

Comment: It can be 2 PostgresOperator or 2 queries within a single SQL file depends on how different those queries are.

Comment: I believe that the main issue here is not referencing `self` in the `execute` method. The end lines should be: `print("Name", self.name)` and `print("Query", self.sql)`. The rest should work.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is OK.
I took your code and created a working example showing `{{ ds }}` (build in [macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.0/templates-ref.html)) is being templated as required.

Create a `.py` file as:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


class SQLOperator(BaseOperator):

   template_fields = ['sql']
   template_ext = ('.sql',)

   @apply_defaults
   def __init__(
           self,
           name = None,
           sql = None,
           *args,
           **kwargs
   ) -> None:

       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.name = name
       self.sql = sql

   def execute(self, context):
       print("Name", self.name)  # <- works
       print("Query", self.sql)  # <- Also works :)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'a',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 24, 2, 0, 0),
}


dag = DAG(
    'sql_operator_test',
     schedule_interval=None,
     default_args=default_args)

sql_task = SQLOperator(
    task_id='sql_process',
    name="Aaa",
    sql="test.sql",
    dag=dag)
```

a `test.sql` file as:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date > {{ ds }}
```

Running it gives:

[image]

And from the task log:

[image]

Comment: +1 helpful, thanks. (If you're wondering where the `{{ds}}` in the SQL is defined, it is predefined by Airflow. "The DAG run’s logical date as YYYY-MM-DD. Same as {{ dag_run.logical_date | ds }}."  (retrieved 2023-08-24 from [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html))

Comment: @jgreve I assumed it is known. Thank you for your conment I will update explnation for it.

Comment: Heh, anybody who looked at the core concept airflow docs before jumping into it _would_ know that. :-)   But I do love your answer, it helped me connect some concepts. Thanks again.