# Migrating large tables using Airflow

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I'm new to using Airflow (and newish to Python.)

I need to migrate some very large MySQL tables to **s3** files using **Airflow**. All of the relevant hooks and operators in **Airflow** seem geared to using **Pandas** dataframes to load the full SQL output into memory and then transform/export to the desired file format.

This is causing obvious problems for the large tables which cannot fully fit into memory and are failing. I see no way to have **Airflow** read the query results and save them off to a local file instead of tanking it all up into memory.

I see ways to **bulk_dump** to output results to a file on the **MySQL** server using the **MySqlHook**, but no clear way to transfer that file to s3 (or to Airflow local storage then to s3).

I'm scratching my head a bit because I've worked in Pentaho which would easily handle this problem, but cannot see any apparent solution.

I can try to slice the tables up into small enough chunks that **Airflow**/**Pandas** can handle them, but that's a lot of work, a lot of query executions, and there are a lot of tables.

What would be some strategies for moving very large tables from a **MySQL** server to **s3**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use Airflow transfer operators if they don't fit to your scale. You can (and probably should) create your very own `CustomMySqlToS3Operator` with the logic that fits to your process.

Few options:

1. Don't transfer all the data in one task. slice the data based on dates/number of rows/other. You can use several tasks of `CustomMySqlToS3Operator` in your workflow. This is not alot of work as you mentioned. This is simply the matter of providing the proper `WHERE` conditions to the SQL queries that you generate. Depends on the process that you build You can define that every run process the data of a single day thus your `WHERE` condition is simple `date_column between execution_date and next_execution_date` (you can read about it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65123416/14624409 ) . Then use `catchup=True` to backfill runs.
2. Use Spark as part of your operator.
3. As you pointed you can dump the data to local disk and then upload it to S3 using [load_file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f94cf99df9d87acee98cc46c8c1e808646e75027/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py#L465) method of `S3Hook`. This can be done as part of the logic of your `CustomMySqlToS3Operator` or if you prefer as Python callable from `PythonOperator`.